# Incompatible operand types ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'id _Nullable')

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an issue connected with assigning of the value to the NSUInteger:

```
self.selectedGroup = GroupType //It is 3 from enum

self.menuItemsPostion = @{[NSNumber numberWithInteger:GroupType]: @0, [NSNumber numberWithInteger:GroupTime]: @1};

NSUInteger itemToSelect = [self isCapturedEntriesContainClienst] ? 1 : self.menuItemsPostion[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.selectedGroup]]; // Incompatible operand types ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'id _Nullable')
```

I understand that method from `NSDictionary`.

`- (nullable id)objectForKey:(id)key;` can return nullable object and that is why is a problem.

I am interested how it is possible to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get `integerValue` of your object in order to assign to your `itemToSelect` which is `NSUInteger`.

```
NSUInteger itemToSelect = [self isCapturedEntriesContainClienst] ? 1 : [self.menuItemsPostion[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.selectedGroup]] integerValue];
```

Comment: Thx i totally forgot about this

Comment: Yes, it is better :)